# Standard file extension for hive ddl script?

Tags: hive, ddl

Is there an accepted convention for a file extension for a hive ddl script? I am purely asking for code organization purpose, so that when I save the script in my repository it is obvious the script is in Hive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard at Apache Hive project is to use .q

You can see examples here

Apache SVN

hive/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientpositive/bucketmapjoin6.q

Answer (score 2):

you can use any extension to run hive scripts.
for example

```
hive -f scriptname.sh
```

but  using .hql is is the best practice so that you can differentiate this file  from other files.

Comment: Thanks for your response. ".hql" does seem logical, but I fear it will confuse devs who use Hinernate's hql. For now I'm going with ".hive".

Comment: agree with your point ,you can also consider hiveql as extension.